# JAVA JDBC mySql Prepared statement Update query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-update, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute the following code

```
package jdbclesson;

import java.sql.*;

public class PreparedQuery {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String url              = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alien?useSSL=false";
    String uname            = "root";
    String pass             = "ma123";
    String query            = "UPDATE student SET username= ? where userid= ? ";
    PreparedStatement stmt  = null;


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

    stmt.setString(1, "tina");
    stmt.setInt(2, 6);


    int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);

    System.out.println(rs);
    stmt.close();
    con.close();

}

}
```

but getting following errors

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? where
>   userid=?' at line 1

My database has only 1 table student with 2 columns userid and username and 10 rows what m i missing

Comment: is user id the primary key or is there any columns which is set to auto increment

Comment: Remove the space here between ? and double quotes (")  `userid= ? ";` and try again please.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Instead of:

```
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

executeUpdate() runs the query of the prepared statement, which is what you want. executeUpdate(query) runs the query passed to the method. You were getting the error because you were passing an SQL with errors (contains ?).

Comment: Exactly the issue I had!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
"UPDATE student SET username= ? ” + ” where userid= ?"; 

int rs=stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Aren't these two lines of code already present in the question?